# In a static control,why is there a tight rectangle surrounding the text?

Tags: c++, winapi, colors, controls

I use static controls to write in the window. Usually, I keep the background color white, and setting the colors of my static controls in the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message was enough (writing in black, background white).
Now, to give a more modern visual, I'm trying to use the DKGRAY color to the window and to the static controls, and writing in white :

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)wParam;
    SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    SetBkColor(hdcStatic, DKGRAY_BRUSH);
    return (INT_PTR)GetStockObject(DKGRAY_BRUSH);
```

It works almost fine :
- The text color is white : good
- The background of the static controls is darkgray : good
- **BUT** the text is written inside a tight black rectangle : What is this tight rectangle sourrounding the text ???? Where does it come from ? How can I change its color ?

[image]

for information, here is an example of the creation of a static control in the WM_CREATE message of the main window :

```
    hsStatic1 = CreateWindowEx(0, L"STATIC", L"Fichier :", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 15, 5, 60, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_STATIC1, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), nullptr);
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could try adding: SetBkMode(hdcStatic, TRANSPARENT);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DKGRAY_BRUSH` is a magic value for `GetStockObject`, it's not an RGB color that you can pass to `SetBkColor()`.

You need to either identify the RGB value of `DKGRAY_BRUSH` and use that in your call to `SetBkColor()`, or pick a specific RGB value to use and create your own brush using `CreateSolidBrush`.

Comment: Thank you ! DKGRAY_BRUSH seems to be RGB(64, 64, 64). It works fine with : SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(64, 64, 64));
            hbrBkgnd = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(64, 64, 64));
            return (INT_PTR)hbrBkgnd;

Comment: @Finelizzyx Make sure you only create the solid brush once, rather than every time you get a `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message, otherwise you will have a GDI resource leak.

Comment: @fin: Why aren't you using `GetStockObject`  for the brush? Doing so means you won't have to worry about cleanup or leaks. You can call [GetObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject) to get a [LOGBRUSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-logbrush) that conveniently holds a `COLORREF` you can use with `SetBkColor`.